# issue plotting .cap files ScaPy Python3

Tags: python-3.x, wireshark, scapy

After reading .cap file using rdpcap successfully, I've been trying to use the function pdfdump but it keeps giving me an error:

"AttributeError: 'SingleTexRunner' object has no attribute 'texoutput' "

here's my code:

```
from scapy.all import *
import pyx

a = rdpcap("the file path..")
a.pdfdump("output filename")
```

anyone got an idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Use `sudo apt-get install python3-pyx` on Linux(Debian, Ubuntu...) to install `pyx` and its dependencies; installing `pyx` with `pip install pyx` is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Python 3.6.0

I've installed scapy with:

```
pip3 install scapy-python3
```

Using wireshark 2.2.3, I saved a dump using the default file format which is `.pcapng`

I've used the same code as you :

```
from scapy.all import *
import pyx

a = rdpcap("test.pcapng")
a.pdfdump("test.pdf")
```

and I obtain a valid pdf.

Comment: still doesn't work , can you post the paths as well, maybe i'm doing something wrong there. thanks

Comment: I've used files in the current directory, but I think the problem is related to the `PyX` package. Can you try to upgrade `pip` with : `pip3 install --upgrade pip` and `PyX` with `pip3 install --force-reinstall --upgrade PyX`

Answer (score 0):

Don't run scapy (if you use the command line) or your script as root. This fixed it for me.